# ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9 not recognizing external monitor since installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: lenovo, intel-graphics, thinkpad, external-monitor

My ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9 isn't recognizing my external monitor ever since I updated to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. The connection is USB-C to USB-C. The computer recognized the monitor before the OS update. My Macbooks recognize the monitor.

The only solutions I've found on other forums pertain to Nvidia graphics cards.

Specs

- graphics: Mesa Intel Xe (TGL GT2)
- processor: 11th gen Intel i7, 2.8 GHz

Appreciate the help.